# how to make nginx proxy pass along connection refused?

Tags: nginx

I have an nginx proxy pointing at an external server. When the external server is down, the nginx proxy returns a 502 bad gateway.

Instead, I'd like nginx to also refuse the connection - How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

After further thought, I think this can't be done.  When nginx is making the request to the external server, it has already accepted the connection from the client